# date_sub function in node-red

Tags: mysql, node-red

Trying and failing to get a date-sub function to work in a node-red function. MySQL db.

Without any date_sub, this works fine (in a function)-

```
var options = { hour12: false };
var nowtime = new Date().toLocaleString("en-GB", options);
msg.topic = `SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowcount FROM \`node-red\`.\`tag_reads\` WHERE  \`datetime\` < "${nowtime}"`;
return msg;
```

With the date_sub part the query fails (with a count of zero even though there are valid records, the query works fine in a conventional jsp)

```
msg.topic = `SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowcount FROM \`node-red\`.\`tag_reads\` WHERE  \`datetime\` > date_sub( "${nowtime}", INTERVAL 90 MINUTE) `;
```

I suspect it is syntax, escape codes etc. The resulting sql string appears to show that datetime (from the table) is not being interpreted as a string (just 'datetime' appears rather than the contents of datetime which are, for example, 10/6/2022, 11:18:43), but, if this was the case then the first select statement would not be working either.

Thoughts appreciated
Ralph

Comment: try replacing the `\\`` ( escaped back quote)  with `'` (single quote)

Comment: Thanks, no difference. I believe it's something related to UK datetime (instead of US datetime) format, when it stores in mysql. Also noticed my insert into and select from doesn't work properly if in the same function. I will try and figure out how to get two separate functions talking to the same db.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like in this statement
`` WHERE  \`datetime\` < "${nowtime}" `` mysql is converting the string to datetime for you.

> MySQL has the ability to compare two different dates written as a string expression.

from [How to do date comparisons in MySQL](https://sebhastian.com/mysql-date-comparisons/)

However, in this statement, `date_sub( "${nowtime}"`, **date_sub** wants the argument to be of type date.

> Syntax
> DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL value interval)

from [MySQL DATE_SUB() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/func_mysql_date_sub.asp)

Comment: Thanks, The issue was that new.Date() formatting (with options) and date.toLocaleString('default', { hour: '2-digit' } doesn't formt properly and ignores the 2-digit part. Hence the dates couldn't be compared properly. Fixed with  if(hour<=9)
hour="0"+hour statements (for all the time parts in the function)